# Problem with concatenated text between two \mathbf elements

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have the following sentence which I want to write in LaTeX:

[image]

So, I have tried to use this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}

We point to the cost of the ith children with 
\mathbf{cost}_{i} , and the probability of same children with,  \mathbf{pro}_{i}



\end{document}
```

But the result shows that some words are concatenated together:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsDpx.png]

Comment: When using math syntax, you should surround it by `$$` - then the error should disappear. Why are you using `\mathbf` - the original text is not bold?

Comment: You get an _error message_ from that input. After an error message pdf output is not intended to be sensible TeX just recovers enough to syntax check more of the document. If you want to ask about an error that is fine but it is better if you state the error in the question (rather than ask about the output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also fixing a bit the grammar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We point to the cost of the \(i\)-th children with
\(\mathbf{cost}_{i}\) and the probability of same 
children with \(\mathbf{pro}_{i}\).

\end{document}
```

Note that in `$i$-th` the “i” represents a math variable. Inline math formulas should always be inside `\(...\)` (although experts tend to use `$...$`).

[image]